# How do I copy a directory tree but not the files in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, rsync, copy

I want to copy about 200 directories & subdirectories from one location to another but I don't want to copy the thousands of files within those directories. I am on Linux.

Note: I don't have enough space to copy everything then delete all the files.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Just found this:

```
rsync -a -f"+ */" -f"- *" source/ destination/
```

http://psung.blogspot.com/2008/05/copying-directory-trees-with-rsync.html

Comment: I prefer this syntax `rsync -a --include='*/' --exclude='*' ${source} ${destination}`.

Answer (score 9):

```
find some/dir -type d -print0 | rsync --files-from=/dev/stdin -0 ...
```

Comment: It would be useful to add what is `-0` and what is the ellipsis. The former, I guess, is for rsync to read the output of find's `print0`.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach is with **find** and **mkdir**:

```
find SOURCE -type d -exec mkdir TARGET/{} \;
```

Just make sure TARGET already exists or use the -p option of mkdir.

Answer (score 3):

You also can do :

```
find inputdir -type d | cpio -pdumv destdir
```

The power of simplicity ;)

Comment: In the beginning of `man cpio` it says: "\_\_WARNING\_\_ The  cpio  utility  is  considered LEGACY based on POSIX specification. Users are encouraged to use other archiving tools for archive creation."

Answer (score 1):

Similarly, using (GNU) tar:

```
find some/dir -type d -print |
tar --no-recursion -T- -c -p -f- |
(cd another/dir && tar -x -p -f-)
```

You don't really need the `-print0` on the find command line or the `-0` on the rsync command line unless you have filenames that contain newline characters (which is possible but highly unlikely).  Tar (and rsync, and cpio) read filenames line-by-line; using a NULL terminator is mostly useful with `xargs`, which normally reads whitespace separated filenames (and so does not handle files/directories with spaces in their names without `-0`).

Answer (score 1):

```
(cd /home/user/source/; find -type d -print0) | xargs -0 mkdir -p
```

Answer (score -1):

```
cp -al
```

Would copy all files with hard links. Same structure, same permissions. (note: hard links, so no storage lost.)

Comment: It is not possible to create hard links across filesystem boundaries

Comment: True, but it wasn't said that it was across filesystem ...

Answer (score -1):

ls -d */
@source: find . -type d -print0 >dirs.txt 
@destination: xargs -0 mkdir -p

This will cause both commands to use nulls as separators instead of whitespaces. Note that the order of -type d and -print0 is important!

Comment: This is not clear and seems incorrect. It seems that the `@source` and `@destination` are indications to the reader, but even so this cannot work.